# log exceptions from log4net to azure table storage in net core

Tags: azure, log4net, azure-table-storage

I am referring the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51841879/is-it-possible-to-customize-azure-table-storage-by-code-log4net-azure) to log exceptions from log4net to azure table storage

Here the appender is created, but the log is not entered to azure table storage.

But the way to provide connection string is not there, kindly help to resolve how to provide the connection string for azure table entry

Comment: Hi, I just use the account name / key instead of the connection string? is it ok for you?

Comment: I follow the link you provided but I can't write log into table storage. Could you give me the complete sample to follow? Thanks:)

Comment: The first Answer by Ivan is working fine, please try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if using account_name / account_key is ok for you.

As my mentioned in my previous post, in app.config -> provide the table name / account_name / account_key:

```
<configuration>    
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
       type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>    
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>    
  <log4net>
    <appender name="AzureLogAppender" type="Log4NetAzureTables.AzureLogAppender, Log4NetAzureTables" >
      <param name="tableName" value="your table name" />
      <param name="accountName" value="your account" />
      <param name="accountKey" value="your account key" />
    </appender>    
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="AzureLogAppender" />
    </root>    
  </log4net>      
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks Ivan for such a great solution, the connection like you said is fine and the Append method in AzureLogAppender also completed with no exceptions, but entry in the azure table is still empty. Is anything missing there?

Comment: Is there anything to do with buffer size? if so how can we set it in AzureLogAppender

Comment: @arunraj414, I will take a look at when I'm back company.

Comment: I figured it out Ivan, my fault to Create storage account object with true since am using https thanks..

Comment: Ivan, Thanks for the help. could you please help me to do the same in azure function, since we cant provide the config files there. do you have any reference on it?. i just gone through this https://stackify.com/logging-azure-functions/

Comment: @arunraj414, I'd like to do some research on this. And could you please raise a new issue about that? And let me know the new issue url. Thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56540243/log-exceptions-from-log4net-to-azure-table-storage-in-azure-function

Comment: @arunraj414, I'll take a look :)