# Log exceptions from log4net to Azure table storage in Azure function

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, log4net, azure-table-storage

I am referring to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51841879/is-it-possible-to-customize-azure-table-storage-by-code-log4net-azure) to log exceptions from log4net to Azure table storage.

Now I need to do the same in Azure functions in .net core, but since there is no config files in Azure functions, I am not able to use the same there.

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Is it function v2 or v1?

Comment: Its function v2

Comment: Do you have any progress on that? Seems a little hard :(

Comment: Not yet Ivan, was busy in some other stuff will try and let you know later

Answer (score 0):

> Now I need to do the same in Azure functions in .net core, but since there is no config files in Azure functions am not able to use the same there

It seems you are trying to read some property what we usually read from config file. Yes you can do it in Azure Function also. There is file name `local.settings.json` you can read your required property from here. See the example below:

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "TableName": "YourTableName",
    "AccountName": "YourAccountName",
    "AccountKey": "YourAccountKey"

  }
}
```

**Read Your Property On Azure Function From `local.settings.json`:**

```cs
  public static class AzureFunctionApp2Arunraj414CaseForGetConfigProperty
{
    [FunctionName("AzureFunctionApp2Arunraj414CaseForGetConfigProperty")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        //Read Request Body
        var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        //Extract Request Body and Parse To Class
        Users objUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(content);

        //You Can Read Your Desired Value from local.settings.json file Like Below
        var yourTableNameFromLocalSettingsJson = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TableName");
        var yourAccountNameFromLocalSettingsJson = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AccountName");
        var yourAccountKeyFromLocalSettingsJson = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AccountKey");


        //I am returning all the property I got from local.settings.json
        var result = new OkObjectResult(yourTableNameFromLocalSettingsJson +" & "+ yourAccountNameFromLocalSettingsJson + " & " + yourAccountKeyFromLocalSettingsJson+ " From local.settings.json");
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Debug & Testing:**

See the screen shot below:

[image]

***Note:** You even can set your property outside of values on `local.settings.json` file as separate property*.